# Adding data frames to a list using looping function in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe

My data contains of vectors named  xDry_i_k and xEthanol_i_k where x can be (A, B, or C), i is pressure (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 GPa), and k is annealing time (0 for now).

So i have tons of vectors named this way, and would like to gather them in a datalist with frames (2 columns) containing for instance ADry_1_0 and AEthanol_1_0 as these two are related and will be used together in future calculations.

I am new to the for-loops, but i tried searching. So far the best i've been able to come up with is:

```
datalist=list()
for(x in paste(LETTERS[1:3])){
  for(i in seq(4,0,-1)){
    for(j in seq(1,length(seq(4,0,-1))*length(paste(LETTERS[1:3])),1)){
      datalist[[j]]=data.frame(xDry_i_0,xEthanol_i_0)
    }
  }
}
```

I know this code probably seems stupid to the experienced one's of you, but it really bothers me why it isn't this simple....!

For now i get the error `"Error in data.frame(xDry_i_0, xEthanol_i_0) : object 'xDry_i_0' not found"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your mistake was made long before you starting writing the first `for` loop here, namely it was a big mistake to create "tons" of isolated objects with a complex numbering scheme in their names. Related objects go in lists. Objects in lists can have names (which are characters) and then you can refer to objects in the list by name. Frankly, it looks like all that information should be in a data frame, and all your x's, i's and k's should be variables.

Comment: ...my point being, that the place to fix this is _before_ you have all those separate objects floating around, not after.

Comment: Thanks, completely makes sense.... That's also where i started, then i began overcomplicating things i guess! Usually it's so much more intuitive when you have .csv files, but this time we had 300 data points written down on paper that had to be manually entered into R. Would you just make 1 gigantic frame with the different variables, pressure, annealing time etc.?

Comment: Oof, on paper? Yeah, I would think the first step would be to transfer it all to a sensibly formed csv (via Excel or other spreadsheet, probably).

Comment: @Joran yes. Using Archimedes principle... Putting some glass on a weight, noting the weight. Then in ethanol, nothing the weight. So we are in a transition period where our teachers want us to stop using excel and start using R, but for the raw data excel is my friend? Thanks! Is there any way to mark your comments as the "answer" to my question, so i can mark it solved?

Comment: @Joran also later on i will have to calculate density using some of the columns. Thus, someone advised me to use a list as they were easier to manage. I would like to keep it in data.frames for now, as i am more familiar with them and the notation, is it doable?? I would like to do it right now, this is like my 5th approach :) :)